# How to group by and get every value of every record MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can i group by type and then get every id of each member of that group? in mysql

i am using php, i need to output one record - that is the type of the group, but in the one record i want to have all the id of the group members, is that posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to select `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`, which will give you a string containing all the IDs (or whatever field you include where I have `id`), separated by commas.

Obviously that's no good for doing further database selection (e.g., joins), but if you just want the IDs available, as you suggested, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).